# OrTools force use of vehicles in sequential order

Tags: or-tools

I have a scenario where I have say 7 vehicles, with each vehicle representing one day of the week.
I then have a number of deliveries which need to be done over the course of the week.
The problem is solved by or-tools fine.
But if I have enough work to fill say only four days, it tends to add these to the last few vehicles (the end of the week), filling the vehicles as much as possible, and then leaving the vehicles at the start of the week empty. Which is almost what I want.
But ideally it should fill the first vehicles and leave the last vehicles empty. I am using the VRPTW example as the basis for more solution and have set up timewindows for each vehicle to service only one day, e.g. 0-1440, 1440-2880, etc.

How could I force it to use the vehicles in sequential order from the first vehicle?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add an increased Vehicle Fixed cost so it is "cheaper" to use first vehicle than the later one ?

Comment: No I haven't. I can give that try.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `Assignment* CompactAssignment(const Assignment& assignment) const;` which could help you but since I never used it, I'm not confident of the result and side effect...

ref (with comments): https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L1125-L1147